# c# stringbuilder - extra double quote in excel export

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, stringbuilder

I'm using Stringbuilder in C# to append data for an export into an Excel .csv file.  I'm formatting a particular field which needs to have its leading zeroes preserved.  In order to do this I have the particular field coded as such:

```
itemNumber = "\"\"" +  itemEntry.Substring(0, pos - 1) + "\"";
csvString.Append(itemNumber);
```

Ultimately after all records are appended, I write out the file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(_reportsOutputPath, fileName.ToString()), csvString.ToString());
```

The problem is, when doing the above, the leading zeros are preserved just fine, but there is an extra double quote at the end, i.e. the data items comes out in the export file as, say, 00000034546"

If I remove the "\"" a the end of the statement, the data item is written out without the double quote, but with leading zeros stripped, and if I leave it in, the extra double quote appears at the end.

Any idea on getting rid of the double quote and preserving leading zeros?

Comment: I would recommend using one of the many CSV nuget packages.  It will prevent issues like this (and ones you haven't come across yet).

Comment: You have an extra double quote at the beginning.

Comment: Data is saved just fine, but the excel keeps formatting it like this. It can't be handled in CSV only.

Comment: aren't you  appending an empty record

Comment: There's no Excel export code here. `xslx` is a ZIP package containing XML files. `CSV` on the other hand is just a text file with specific formatting. You can use Epplus to create real `xlsx` files if you want. If you really need CSV files, check CsvHelper. It takes care of some CSV weirdness like allowing newlines inside of quoted fields

Comment: Are you viewing this in Excel only? Excel will format certain things in ways other than how you enter them. For example, if you open a new Excel file and enter 00000034546, it'll strip those zeroes. It shouldn't happen in something like Notepad.

Comment: `there is an extra double quote at the end,` because that's what this code does - append a string with an ending double quote to `csvString`. To avoid this you'd have to either check whether the field is the last in the line, or *remove* the end quote when moving to the next line. Or use `String.Join("\"",items)`

Comment: @BrootsWaymb leading zeroes in numbers aren't significant. That's why they are aren't displayed. *Formatting* is a different story, and Excel does allow formatting through the Cell Style dialog. CSV files are just text though, they have no formatting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I know that. That's what I' saying.